# how can i rip zuma's revenge sprites from the nintendo ds rom?

Tags: unpacking

opening the bin file as a tile in tinke gives me the following:
[image]

there are just random pixels that don't contain any useful sprites

and it's the same if i open the file in gimp
[image]

my directory for the zuma's revenge nintendo ds files is in downloads -> melonds + zuma's revenge -> roms
[image]

and the bin files are already extracted but opening those bin files just gives me random pixels. can anyone help?

and please ignore eveything else that's not important